# Параметры перевода видео в mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, видео

Какие параметры нужно ввести (и есть ли они), чтобы преобразовать видео (avi, mkv) произвольного разрешения и качества в mp4 (видео-кодек h.264, аудио - aac) с минимальными потерями качества (тот же размер видео, тот же битрейт видео/аудио)?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию часто кодек для h264 выключен из-за всяких патентных проблем. Однако, ffmpeg можно собрать так, чтобы он работал. Если у вас есть правильная сборка, то конвертировать можно так:

```
ffmpeg -i INFILE -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -crf 22 -threads 0 OUTFILE.mp4
```

Если у вас проблемы в получении такой сборки, то можете поискать инструкции. Например, вот эта: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095